# MYSQL - Get all %char% and %text% columns with value length of at least x?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way I can do something like the following?

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table` WHERE (`Type` LIKE "%char%" OR `Type` LIKE "%text%") AND MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(`Field`)) >= $php_variable
```

The output should include all `%char%` and `%text%` fields that have values whose lengths are equal to or greater than a PHP variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to information_schema, you can grab the data easily.

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where (data_type = '%char' or data_type like '%text')
and character_maximum_length > 10
```

Comment: I believe you meant `data_type LIKE '%char'`. And I have to specify the database name and table name using this method, but that's not a problem. Thank you.